# Android “Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission”

Tags: java, android

I am developing remote control application for Android.
I am getting this issue when injecting motion event outside the application.

**Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission**

Is there any solution to fix this without root permission?
Hope your reply
Thanks

Comment: You can check if the CPU is intel and spectre into the Android OS to change your apps permissions.

Comment: @AlanStack Can you please comment more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any solution to fix this without root permission

No, you cannot hold this permission on non-rooted device as this permission is signature based.

> android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS
>
> Allows an application to inject user events (keys, touch, trackball)
>   into the event stream and deliver them to ANY window.  Without this
>   permission, you can only deliver events to windows in your own
>   process.
>
> **Not for use by third-party applications**

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#L2515

Comment: INJECT_EVENTS permission has nothing to do with root. It just requires that app to be signed with the ROM's platform key. (i.e)If you have signed your app with the ROM's platform key then you don't require any root permission.

Comment: That's technically true and also pretty obvious. However it does not apply to 99,9999999% of users, who does not have platform keys and simply need root.